# Find command with regex not working as intended

Tags: regex, sed, find

I am trying to print all those files which doesn't contain a imdb id in their filename. For those aren't aware , here are some exmaples of the id's

```
tt0111161
tt0068646
tt0071562
tt0468569
tt0050083
tt0108052
tt0167260
tt0110912
tt0060196
tt0120737
```

Just for the ease of this question i have created 10 files , 5 of which have these id's in their name and the rest doesn't .

```
❯ ls
'random_name1 tt9264728.mp4'   
'random_name2 tt0111161.mp4'       
'random_name3 tt0071562.mp4'   
'random_name4 tt0050083.mp4'
'random_name5 tt0108052.mp4' 
'random name6.mp4'
'random name7.mp4'
'random name8.mp4'
'random name9.mp4'
'random name10.mp4'   
       
❯find . -regextype sed -not -regex "tt\d{7}" -type f -print     
                         
./random_name4 tt0050083.mp4
./random_name1 tt9264728.mp4
./random name6.mp4
./random name7.mp4
./random_name3 tt0071562.mp4
./random_name2 tt0111161.mp4
./random_name5 tt0108052.mp4
./random name8.mp4
./random name9.mp4
./random name10.mp4
```

As can be seen from above , find is also printing those files which have the id in their names . Also its adding './' before each result for some reason which i don't need.

Expected result -

```
random name6.mp4
random name7.mp4
random name8.mp4
random name9.mp4
random name10.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a POSIX BRE regex flavor, the following will work for you:

```sh
find . -regextype sed -not -regex ".*tt[0-9]\{7\}[^/]*$" -type f -print
```

Note:

- You need to escape `{}` in range quantifiers in POSIX BRE
- `\d` is not supported, you need `[0-9]` to match a digit in a POSIX regex
- You need to provide a pattern that will match the *entire* string in a `find` regex pattern.

The regex matches

- `.*` - any text, zero or more chars
- `tt` - a `tt` string
- `[0-9]\{7\}` - seven digits
- `[^/]*` - zero o rmore chars other than a `/` char
- `$` - end of string.